# Can't install gmagick on Windows 7 XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, gmagick

I have XAMPP 1.8.1 with PHP 5.4.7 installed. When I add `php_gmagick_ts.dll` to my php.ini (I made sure that I need the **ts** and not the **nts** version), upon restarting Apache I'm getting these errors:

> The procedure entry point php_checkuid_ex could not be located in the
>   dynamic link library php5ts.dll

and after that one:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_gmagick_ts.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is currently no GraphicsMagick DLL available working with PHP 5.4 on Windows.

As the availability of php_gmagick_(n)ts.dll for latest PHP versions is always a problem, I recommend that you either drop back to PHP 5.3 ([DLLs available here](http://valokuva.org/)) or that you use the standalone version of GraphicsMagick and call it from within PHP using exec() commands.

Comment: Thanks Jpsy, I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I've just tried it, but this XAMPP is VC6 and VC9 is required (as you wrote in another question here). I'm really getting desperate here. Maybe I should try ImageMagic instead. Any advice?

Comment: Yes, these are the problems that go along with using php_gmagick DLL. I have had my share of them too.
You have to find a DLL that exactly matches your PHP version (PHP version number, thread safe/Non thread safe, Visual Studio runtime version VC6/VC9).
I do not know of any VC6 version of the DLL, so your option is to use the VC9 version of PHP 5.3. You can download it here: http://windows.php.net/download/